# Openwebload in Linux

Tags: linux, debian

I am trying to install the latest version of openwebload in Debian but it's pretty old. Is this project dead? Where can I get the latest version (last update is from 2001 ?!)

Comment: http://openwebload.sourceforge.net/ was also last updated in 2001, so it would seem to have been abandoned. Have you looked at other load testing tools such as ApacheBench?

Comment: No I haven't, can it be used with Nginx? Thanks

Comment: I am doing my darndest to inhibit the impulse to post a "Let Me Google That for You" link.

Comment: Wikipedia: "Originally designed to test the Apache HTTP Server, it is actually generic enough to test any web server."

Comment: Original author of OpenWebLoad here - must admit I haven't maintained it for years  Stumbled upon this post by random. Anyway FWIW, I am considering reviving it, but this time written in rust and with HTTPS support.

Answer (score -1):

Download and install http://archive.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-2.95/libstdc++2.10-glibc2.2_2.95.4-27_i386.deb .

It did work for Debian 6.

Comment: The link is to a topic about Castle Wolfenstein, not Openwebload. If this is what you intended, I think a thorough explanation of your thinking would be necessary. Until then, -1

Comment: True I will remove the link but that is where I got the link to the gcc.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install gcc` should suffice for that, `sudo apt-get install build-essential` to get a reasonably complete developer toolchain.